# tableView does not show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This problem occured in two of my view controllers.When I ran the app, the tableView does not even show up, not to mention the data that should be displayed in the table. I cannot post a screenshot here cuz my reputation is not high enough.

Here is my code.

```
#import "OngoingTournamentTableViewController.h"
#import "TournamentTableViewCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define kOngoingTournamentURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/d4leq2cs?apikey=xgp4nU6xA9UcBWSe0MIHcBVbAWz5v4wR"]


@interface OngoingTournamentTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ongoingTournament;

@end

@implementation OngoingTournamentTableViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kOngoingTournamentURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedTournamentData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

- (void)fetchedTournamentData:(NSData *)tournamentResponseData {
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:tournamentResponseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray *myOngoingTournament = [[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"collection1"];

self.ongoingTournament = myOngoingTournament;

[self.tableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"%@", self.ongoingTournament);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.ongoingTournament count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tournamentCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"tournamentCell"];
}

NSDictionary *tournaments = [self.ongoingTournament objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *title = [[tournaments objectForKey:@"Title"] objectForKey:@"text"];
NSString *venue = [tournaments objectForKey:@"Venue"];

cell.textLabel.text = title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = venue;

return cell;
}


@end
```

I have assigned classes to the tableView and prototype cell. Any suggestions?

And I don't get anything on the console, yet the url works fine in the browser.

Thank you in advance and again sorry for being such a burden.

Comment: shouldn't the view controller be a subclass of the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Are the data source methods being called?

Comment: @PhillipMills how do i do that

Comment: @rakeshbs yeah it is

Comment: is dispatch_async block executing and did u get `data`?

Comment: No it's not, I don't get anything from the console, not even NSException

Comment: @rakeshbs No it's not. I m not getting anything on my console

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return [self.ongoingTournament count];` and see if it gets hit.  Better still, print out the value being returned there.

Comment: @PhillipMills hi it doesn't get hit

Comment: @PhillipMills and the console doesnot print anything

Answer (score 0):

youre going to have to adopt uitableview protocols and set your tableview delegate and datasource.

if the header file of your view controller you will need to look something like this

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

then in yor implementation somewhere when setting up your tableview

```
mytableview.delegate = self;
mytableview.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programatically like @myte said, or in storyboard and link your tableview to the controller and then select "`Delegate`" and do it again with "`Datasource`".

Then in the .h modify the `@interface` line like this :

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download your data using `NSURLConnection` like below. Call your f

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:kOngoingTournamentURL];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self fetchedTournamentData:data]
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, but i did that and it still doesn't work

Comment: can you check whether self.tableview is nil? also check if they are linked in storyboard and delegate and datasource are set

Comment: hey the delegate and datasource are both set